# SQL multiple AS columns from WHERE

Tags: sql, select, google-bigquery, where-clause

I have a table

```
name | age | city
-------------
joe | 42 | berlin
ben | 42 | munich
anna | 22 | hamburg
pia | 50 | berlin
georg | 42 | munich
lisa | 42 | berlin
```

Now I would like to get all 42 year old in different columns by city

```
berlin | munich
-------------
joe | ben
lisa | georg
```

So I would need something like

```
SELECT (
SELECT  name AS berlin WHERE city = "berlin"
UNION
SELECT name AS munich WHERE city = "munich")
FROM TABLE
WHERE
age = 42
```

Best from Berlin
Joerg

Comment: BigQuery DOES NOT support (most likely `yet`) PIVOT - but there is always "workaround" - please clarify your specific use case so we can answer with appropriate one. Also - there is already quite a number of questions with answers on this very topic  - have you tried to search? key words would be `PIVOT`, `TRANSPOSE`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want aggregation:

```
select max(case when city = 'berlin' then name end) as berlin,
       max(case when city = 'munich' then name end) as munich
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by city order by name) as seqnum
      from t
      where city in ('berlin', 'munich') and age = 42
     ) t
group by seqnum
order by seqnum;
```

Comment: do you think there is no 42 olders in Hamburg or any other German city? :o)

Answer (score 0):

Using [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017) for example I did it with SQL Server. Hope this can help you.

```
DECLARE @columns varchar(MAX);
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
CREATE TABLE #Table
(
idPerson int,
firstName varchar(10),
age int,
city varchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO #Table
SELECT '1', 'joe', '42','berlin' UNION ALL
SELECT '2', 'ben', '42','munich' UNION ALL
SELECT '3', 'Ana', '22','hamburg' UNION ALL
SELECT '4', 'pia', '50','berlin' UNION ALL
SELECT '5', 'george', '42','munich' UNION ALL
SELECT '6', 'lisa', '42','munich'



--SELECT * from #Table

 SET @columns = STUFF(
 (
 SELECT
   ',' + QUOTENAME(LTRIM(city))
 FROM
   (SELECT DISTINCT city
    FROM #Table
   ) AS T
 ORDER BY
 city
 FOR XML PATH('')
 ), 1, 1, '');

 SET @sql = N'
 SELECT
   * 
  FROM
  (  
  SELECT  idPerson ,firstName ,age ,city 
  FROM #Table
    --WHERE age = 42
  ) AS T
  PIVOT   
  (
  MAX(firstName)
  FOR city IN (' + @columns + N')
  ) AS P order by age;'; 

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
DROP TABLE #Table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help! Based on the answer of Gordon Linhoff I got this solution:

SELECT max(case when city = 'berlin' then name end) as berlin,
       max(case when city = 'munich' then name end) as munich
FROM TABLE
WHERE age = 42
;

Comment: This returns only one row, so it does not return the result set that you want.

Comment: oh, thanks, then I asked the wrong question or actually wrote a wrong example result. In the end it is what I want.